# How to capture value from Google Maps Searchbox and push to a new div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm new to coding in general, but I have a question regarding how to capture the value from Google Maps Searchbox to try and then dynamically create a `div` tag that will display a row with value of whatever was entered into the Searchbox.

I have tried creating an `.onclick()` event but proved useless since the Searchbox doesn't require a submit button to find results.

```
// Adding event listener for when user clicks the add-bttn
$("#search").on("click", function() {

// variable for using the search functionality and adding it to the itinerary for the first day
var itineraryInput = $("#form-control").val();

console.log(itineraryInput);

})


.then(function() {

    var row = $("<div>");
    row.addClass("attraction");

    row.append("<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>");


    $("#trans_first").prepend(row);
});
```

the error that I get in the console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on(...).then is not a function.

I simply want to grab the value from the Searchbox but have no idea about getting that result.

Comment: Why do you want to use `.then()`? Can't you just not move the code into the click event?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use then, you can just put your function inside the click event listener:

```js
// Adding event listener for when user clicks the add-bttn
$("#search").on("click", function() {

  // variable for using the search functionality and adding it to the itinerary for the first day
  var itineraryInput = $("#form-control").val();

  console.log(itineraryInput);

  var row = $("<div>");
  row.addClass("attraction");

  row.append("<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>");


  $("#trans_first").prepend(row);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label> Search
<input id="form-control" >
</label>
<button id="search">Search </button>

<div id="trans_first">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. That actually help resolve the issue!